# How do I interact with SQL in a Windows Store App

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I've been asked to begin developing a Windows Store version of our company's LOB web application. What's the best way to go about interacting with out data store?

My first inclination is to go the HTML/JavaScript(JQuery) route and use a web service to retrieve the data, but I'd like to attempt to use C#/XAML as I'm familiarizing myself with XAML and this would be the perfect opportunity to take a deep dive into XAML.

Is Javascript the only way to communicate with out sql servers, or can I achieve this through C#/XAML? If so can anyone point me in the right direction or perhaps provide a general example of  how to "connect the dots" between the WINRT framework and SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish it with C# or JavaScript and you'd do it pretty much the same way, via services. Windows Store (C#/VB) applications don't have the same capabilities as desktop apps do to access databases via interfaces like ODBC, JDBC, SQL Native Client, etc., so you won't be connecting your Win RT app with SQL, you'll be connecting it via a hosted service that itself directly accesses the database.

Depending on how your LOB web application is partitioned, you may be able to expose existing functionality as a service layer and then invoke those services from your Windows Store app via HTTP requests. The [HttpClient sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664) should help and depending on the service implementation you can also use [WCF client capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556233.aspx) in Windows Store apps.

Comment: The link you provided looks like a nice starting point. I already have a wcf service running so I'll try tweaking that and accessing it from my store app. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

XAML is a declarative language based on XML, javascript is a scripting language. I'd suggest reading some basics first before you dive in.

And yes, you can use C# to communicate with remote servers and/or webservices...

Maybe this will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974581.aspx

Comment: I was referring to JavaScript in terms of combining it with HTML to build the Metro app, as opposed to the C#/XAML approach.

Comment: @user609926, in that case sure, no problem.. XAML can substitute HTML very easily and even more... C# itself is a powerful language, so there shouldn't be any problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want local database you can use SQLite but I'm guesing that you want external Db

One of my apps is connecting via web with DB. The DB is in Azure. I connect them by simple .net webapi. So my Windows Store App is getting data via webapi from Azure db via HttpClient. It's easy to do. 3 lines of code. I'm sending data as a JSON serialized string sa they take minimum space. It's a good way but you need to remember that when you want to use big objects etc you need to think about caching results, checking the cache, cleaning it etc.

Comment: Windows store app profile excludes the entire System.Data.* namespace. Can I use the namespaces and classes (with the help of which we connect to SQLite) inside the store app project itself or I refer them in another project which is referred in my windows store app project? I believe they will all be async in nature irrespective of this case.