# Windows Universal App and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, uwp

i need help some here :(

I'm relatively new to programming, and now i'm trying to creat an UWP which display results of query executed on SQL Server, but i can't figure out how can i connect to the server.

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: From the Fall Creators Update you can do it "the old way". More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app

Answer (score 1):

Only through an intermediate server with RestAPI