# SqlConnection in Portable Class Library

Tags: uwp, portable-class-library, sqlconnection

So I just started to work on a bigger project which includes a web application, a windows service and a UWP.
I thought that with one code base one portable class library i can serve all projects.

Now my first problem is, that i can't use the SqlConnection class.
I get following error:

> Error CS7069  Reference to type 'Component' claims it is defined in
>   'System', but it could not be found

What I'm doing wrong? Or is it not possible? What would be the right way?

Thanks guys!

Comment: For using SQL Server in UWP app, you may refer to [How to connect to SQL server database from a Windows 10 UWP app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app).

Answer (score 1):

UWP doesn't support `SqlConnection` so you'll need to do your database access differently there.

Specifically, the error is saying that the type `Component` isn't in the `System` namespace. This is because in a PCL you only have access to types that are included in all the platforms your PCL targets.

Comment: Hey Matt! Thank you for your quick reply. Is there another possibility to communicate with a MSSQL database?

Comment: @James an MSSQL database normally requires a constant connection. Because this can't be guaranteed in a UWP which may be used in a mobile environment the standard practice is to expose the necessary database access functionality via a web based API and have the app call that. Alternatively, if your UWP app is desktop only you could create a regular .Net app that connects to the database and use the desktop bridge to allow a UWP app to connect.