# Why UWP app can not use PCL that references classic .Net dll?

Tags: .net, uwp, portable-class-library

We have a huge collection of classic .Net libraries written in anything from .Net 3.5 to 4.6. This includes our core business logic and data model classes we use across various .Net solutions using WCF, Web API, Asp.Net, WPF and Windows Forms. It is only natural therefore that when looking into creating a UWP app, we'd need to reuse some of these .Net dlls.

I've create a portable class library (PCL) in which I reference one of our .Net 4.5 dlls. I then created a class in the PCL that implements one of the 4.5 classes:

```
using DODServiceLib.Models;

namespace PortableClassLibrary
{
    public class UtilityStats : ProcessorStats
    {
    }
}
```

ProcessorStats is from the 4.5 dll, DODServiceLib.Models.

In my UWP app, I've added a project reference to the PCL, PortableClassLibrary and added a using statement in my code behind, this is where I need to use the implementation of my .Net class:

```
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PortableClassLibrary;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var utilityStats = new UtilityStats();
        }
    }
}
```

When building the solution, I get these errors against the UWP HelloWorld app:

```
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: DODServiceLib, Version=20.17.7.28, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'DODServiceLib.dll'
```

Why is the UWP app looking for a reference to the .Net DLL (DODServiceLib) when it only uses the PCL?

Can I not use a PCL like this as a "wrapper" for a classic .Net library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the UWP app looking for a reference to the .Net DLL (DODServiceLib) when it only uses the PCL?

It's normal. Your PCL add added reference to that .NET DLL, so it certainly will look for this dll. But this dll is not support in UWP. That's reason why you will get the exception. UWP project can reference Universal Windows Class Library, Portable Library or Windows Runtime Component.It doesn't mean that you could use PCL to wrap the classic .NET library.That's entirely different thing. I think what you need to do is copy all the code from your .NET library into PCL and then start to eliminate/replace all code which doesn't fit.

Comment: The problem is that my .Net library uses Entity Framework to connect to a SQL Server database and I haven't been able to get EF to work in the PCL. I can add EF via Nuget to the PCL but then there is not Entity Data Model class available under add-new-items. Then found another post stating that System.Data is not supported by PCL so that renders PCL's useless in my opinion, at least as far as data access is concerned.

Comment: The Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (build 16299) UWP apps can now access SQL Server directly via the standard NET classes (System.Data.SqlClient), so, you could use these APIs to make your own sql helper class in PCL. See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app) for more details.