# How to deploy WCF Service with UWP Application?

Tags: c#, wcf, uwp

I have a solution which works perfectly while debugging in Visual Studio, but will not run on the same machine if I deploy in release mode. I'm assuming it is because my WCF Library Service is not getting deployed and starting with it. It seems that it only runs in debug mode.

The solution is a UWP Application (version 1607), so not Fall Creator's update. I'm using WCF Library Service to pull data from a SQL Server into a net standard 1.3 pcl. In Visual Studio it works, but not when I click on the deployed UWP app.

Is there something I'm missing? I did see a comment about adding the WCF App.Config code to my launching app's APP.Config file, but a UWP app doesn't have one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: And this is only side loaded application.

Comment: I don't really get your setup... you have a WCF service library? Where is the service hosted? And why is the app not just calling the DB directly?

Comment: A UWP app pre Fall Creator's Edition does not have the API's to connect directly to an on-prem sql server. So, I'm not hosting the Web Service anywhere right now. Just in VS. I was hoping to avoid hosting it either in IIS or a web server, and just run it just like VS does.

Comment: The web service needs to be hosted somewhere for the installed app to utilize it.  Visual Studio is likely using IIS Express to host the site when you run it locally.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys. That's what I was afraid of. There just doesn't seem to be any path open, pre fall creators update, to push out an app with a connection to a sql server, which an end user can simply click on and start using without someone from IT deploying an IIS WCF on the device, or creating a web server to host it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the Fall update... Windows Store (8, 8.1) and UWP apps are run in "sandboxes" and cannot communicate with the SQL Server without the use of a service.  To do what you're looking for, you would want a WPF or Windows Forms app.  Good luck!

Comment: According to this question, you can now use System.Data.SqlClient to directly connect to a sql database: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app

Comment: But, I cannot upgrade to the Fall Creator's update at this time. So, I'm kind of out of luck.

Comment: Network isolation blocks UWP apps from local network access. Look up checknetisolation.exe for info and how to disable this for your app. VS by default disables it while debugging