# UWP SQL connection Error [c#]

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp

I try to connect to a SQL Server 2008 instance with SQL Server credentials.

With a WPF app, I have no problem.

I follow this example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases

I have read this:
[How to connect to SQL server database from a Windows 10 UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app)

My connection string is:

```
static private string connectionString = 
     @"Data Source=SERVER\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=Something;
       Integrated Security=false;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pass";

conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

try
{
    conn.Open();
}
catch(Exception z)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(z.ToString());
}
```

I get this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - L’opération a réussi)

If I try

```
static private string connectionString = 
    @"Data Source=SERVER\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog = Something;
      Integrated Security=true;User ID = user;Password= pass";
```

I get this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Failed to generate SSPI context. ErrorCode=DowngradeDetected

The same error with Integrated Security=SSPI

If someone has an idea please?

Thanks
Benoit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try with a new VM and SQL EXPRESS 2014
It's working.

I think UWP and SQL SERVER 2008 are not compatible.

Thanks for your help Rami.

Benoit

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the appropriate capabilities in your appx manifest that are required for accessing the resource on your network. Open Package.appxmanifest in VS and go to the 'Capabilities' tab.

Comment: The following boxes are checked:
Internet (client)
Internet (Client and Server)
Private network
Enterprise authentification

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this code

   optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source = SERVER\SQLSERVER; Initial Catalog = Something; Integrated Security = False; User Id = user; Password = pass; MultipleActiveResultSets = True");
2. Make sure that the TCP is enabled in the SQL Server Configuration Manager
   [image]
3. I remember
     The case can be solved by installing a small repair for the server
   Before that, try another server
4. I remembered the third case
   Install Kerberos
   See link
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/811889/how-to-troubleshoot-the-cannot-generate-sspi-context-error-message
   Download and install from the link
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046

Comment: 1. Same error
2. TCP is enable
3. I have no other server for testing.
Where can I download the fix, please?

Comment: I modified the answer by adding a new solution I think will solve your problem

Comment: I tried it, it seems not working. When I launch kerberos test, I ve got an error.
Let me the end of the Week to make more testing.
You may right, probably uwp app wants sspi connection. My server may be not configure correctly for this type of connection. For Info, it is win srv 16 with mssql2008. This server has no domain.

Comment: I think the Windows  Installer service does not work for your windows
Maybe the error you got is yours
The Windows Installer Service Could Not Be Accessed

Try running and repairing Windows Installer 
As in the article or try another article
https://windowsreport.com/windows-installer-service-could-not-be-accessed/

Comment: Another suggestion
Try using a free or trial sql server on a hosting site 
that to find the cause of the problem...

Comment: I had no problem with the setup.
the problem is when I launch KerberosConfigMgr.exe. 
I click on connect - with no credential - I have an error :
 the was an issue with accessing useraccount information from the system. Please check log at ….

Comment: Log follow :
`19/07/2018 21:25:20 Info: Connect to WMI, \root\cimv2
19/07/2018 21:25:39 Error: Access of User Principal information failed System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalServerDownException: Impossible de contacter le serveur. System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException: Le serveur LDAP n'est pas disponible.
   à System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.Connect()
`
There is an ldap error.