# EFCore SqlClient error LocalDB

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core, localdb

I'm testing EFCore 2.0.3 in a UWP project using `System.Data.SqlClient`.

If I connect to a SQL Server instance, it works OK, but when changing to LocalDB, I get an error:

> LocalDB is not supported on this platform

My connection string is this:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFileName=\Statistics.mdf;Initial Catalog=Statistics;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

My LocalDB version is (using SQL Server 2016): v13.1.4001.0

EFCore 2.0.3 does not support LocalDB, or am I missing something?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 10 17134

Answer (score 0):

From .Net standard 2.0, we can use the SQL Server database in a UWP app, but your UWP app must configure target version and min version 16299 or more higher version. You can change them by right click your project => Properties => Application tab.

You can see the document [Use a SQL Server database in a UWP app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/sql-server-databases) and the sample: https://github.com/StefanWickDev/IgniteDemos/tree/master/NorthwindDemo

Besides, here is also a similar thread you can have a reference:

[How to connect to SQL server database from a Windows 10 UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32885735/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-database-from-a-windows-10-uwp-app)

**---Update---**

Currently, UWP app doesn't support the LocalDB on 16299 and 17134. But in my test, LocalDB can work well in WPF app and Console app, this is my connect string:

```
        public string LocalDBConnectionString = @"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True;
Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;
TrustServerCertificate=True;
ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False";
```

Comment: I'm using 16299, and I used that link example, but my question is not for a SQL Instance like SQL Express, but for LocalDB. With localDB using that connection string I'm unable to connect to the local DB.

Comment: @J_PT Currently, UWP app doesn't support LocalDB, but it can work well in wpf app. See the details in my **Update** part.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help, in WPF I can also connect, but not sure how I could translate gthat to UWP that is the project target...

Comment: Unfortunately, the LocalDB can not be used in UWP platform now.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT Is there an issue to get this fixed? I am having problems with 17763